# How do I get the old permission page for Facebook applications

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am confused how to get old permission page for my applications.

- `http://vishwa.us/1/red/` -- My application
- `http://apps.facebook.com/howlucky/?r=16`  -- Other application

The other application mentioned above gets the old permission page. But my application is getting the new permission page. I have disabled the enhanced authentication dialog in advanced settings too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can get the old authentication dialog anymore, applications that were migrated to the new authentication dialog are "stuck" with that.

As it says in the *[Launching the Improved Auth Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/633/)* official blog post:

> On February 1, 2012, all apps will be enabled for the improved dialog,
>   but those that haven’t fully configured their dialog can disable the
>   setting in the Developer App until February 15, at which time it will
>   be turned on for all apps.

I guess that the application you linked in your question was just not migrated for some reason, I can't explain why.

As for the link to your application, you're just doing it wrong so it looks really bad.
You, for some  reason, used *display=touch* which results in a bad experience for users who try to use it via a normal web browser. You should use *display=page* which is also the default (as you can see in the [Dialog documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/)), so you can just neglect the *display* property all together.